# Output Clash probabilities of two different inputs which undergoes AES-128 and then HMAC

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, hmac

I am required to generate a unique output string for each of my input which is also cryptographically secure.

I am currently using https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption as the library to first encrypt and then hash my inputs. 
According to the readme file of the library, "Messages are encrypted with AES-128 in CBC mode and are authenticated with HMAC-SHA256 (Encrypt-then-Mac). PKCS7 padding is used to pad the message to a multiple of the block size. HKDF is used to split the user-provided key into two keys: one for encryption, and the other for authentication. It is implemented using the `openssl_` and `hash_hmac` functions."

As the output is different each time I run the algorithm. From what I gather, this is because of different IV during the encryption phase. So my question is, will there ever be an output collision for the two different input and same key.

i.e. can `HMAC(K2, AES-128(M1, K, IV1)) == HMAC(K2, AES-128(M2, K, IV2))` be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, will there ever be an output collision for the two different input and same key.
>
> i.e. can `HMAC(K2, AES-128(M1, K, IV1)) == HMAC(K2, AES-128(M2, K, IV2))` be true?

Yes, it can happen, but the probability is negligible (order of magnitude: one in 10^38) without any newly discovered weaknesses in SHA256.

More interesting for a theoretical attacker is: With a 128-bit IV, the chance of a [birthday collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is 1 in 2^64. If you can convince an attacker to encrypt approximately 18,000,000,000,000,000,000 blocks of data using this library (an absurdly high number far outside of the reach of most attackers today), you'll get an IV to repeat (with 50% probability).

Most AES keys will only ever be used to encrypt less than 2^50 bytes of data, so this isn't really a practical concern for most people. However, in the interest of spinal tap security, I implemented a workaround to version of Defuse's encryption library:

> The library already uses HKDF-SHA256 to split the key into two keys:
>
> - An encryption key (for AES)
> - An authentication key (for HMAC)
>
> In verison 2, in addition to a 128 bit random nonce for CTR mode, the library will also generate a 256 bit random salt for HKDF. This means that, even in the event that you get a birthday collision in the IV, the AES (and HMAC) keys will not be the same, so no information is leaked.
>
> In order to get a useful collision, you would need the 128-bit nonce and 256-bit HKDF salt to be identical. This gives us 384 bits of breathing room, while the security still depends on a 256-bit "master" key (the one the library user manages).

In short, the 50% point of a birthday collision occurs after 2^192 messages rather than 2^64.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input to HMAC is different each time, the collision resistance is the same as that of the underlying hash function. For SHA-256 the probability is `2-n/2 = 2-128` where `n` is the output size (assuming the full output is used as authentication tag). This is still (probably) beyond our current lifetime. It's important to note that `n/2` and not simply `n` was used here, because the birthday problem can be applied to collision resistance.

It's important to note that HMAC in its intended use here should not be evaluated with [collision resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance), but rather [preimage resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) in mind where the probability is actually much much lower. Therefore, with the currently available attacks, it is still safe to use HMAC-MD5, but [a better attack can come along which might break that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9340/13022). HMAC-SHA256 is a safe choice for the moment and in the (near) future.